# doFilter() overridden method httpRequest.getUserPrincipal() always return NullPoint Exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, keycloak

I created spring boot application. i have used following dependencies.
Spring boot version is 2.1.0.RELEASE

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-saml-servlet-filter-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Security configuration class look like following.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator").authenticated();
    http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/assets/logout.html");
 }
 }
```

Filter class look like following:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", initParams = {
    @WebInitParam(
            name = "keycloak.config.file",
            value = "./config/saml.xml"
    )})
public class SingleSignOnFilter extends SamlFilter {
    private static final String loginGc = "/gc/";
    private static final String logoutUrl = "/gc/assets/logout.html";

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
FilterChain chain)throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    String requestPath = httpRequest.getRequestURI();

    boolean needAuthentication = !requestPath.equals(logoutUrl);
    boolean alreadyLoginGc = !requestPath.equals(loginGc);

    if (needAuthentication) {
        if (alreadyLoginGc) {
            super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
        } else {
            httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no 
                store");
            super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
        }
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
}
```

when i call `httpRequest.getUserPrincipal();` this method its will return Nullpoint Exception.

and when i trying to get authenticated user its will return `annonymousUser`.

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
.getAuthentication();
 auth.getName();
```

Saml.xml look like following:

```
<keycloak-saml-adapter>
<SP entityID="https://localhost/gc" sslPolicy="NONE">
    <PrincipalNameMapping policy="FROM_NAME_ID"/>
    <IDP entityID="************************">
        <SingleSignOnService requestBinding="POST" 
validateResponseSignature="true"

bindingUrl="********************************"/>
        <SingleLogoutService requestBinding="REDIRECT" 
responseBinding="REDIRECT"

redirectBindingUrl="***************************"/>
        <Keys>
            <Key signing="true">
                <CertificatePem>
                    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                    ##########################
                    ###### Dummy Data ########
                    ##########################
                    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
                </CertificatePem>
            </Key>
        </Keys>
    </IDP>
</SP>
</keycloak-saml-adapter>
```

Comment: @dur  `SamlFilter` is from a `keycloak-saml-servlet-filter-adapter` library.

Comment: Then you have to switch it. First authenticate then access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the filter implementation you are using handles the required logic for spring security underneath but it is clear that `SecurityContextHolder` is not populated since there are no adapters configured to do so.

Keycloak provides a [Spring Security Adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-security-adapter.html), try to use it. It will populate `httpRequest.getUserPrincipal()` as well.